# Get content of image instead of url after ajax completion

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, image, base64

In jQuery I have:

```
url = "http://example.com/";
$('div').append('<img src="'+url+'/get_image/10">');
```

In Laravel I have a function named get_image contains:

```
public function get_image($id)
{
    $media = Media::where('id', $id)->first()->file_path;
    return 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($media));
}
```

but when I open the page the src attribute contains:

`http://example.com/show_image/36`

however I want this to be shown:

`data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`

that the result would be the image in base64_encoded.

How can I fix this to show the base64 content of image instead of the url?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use Get fist ;

```
$.get( "http://example.com/show_image/36", function( data ) {
  $('div').append('<img src="'+data+'"');
});
```

Hope This Help,